# Volkswagen GTI OBDII Readiness

Tags: obd-ii, electronic-control-module, emissions

I have a 2015 Volkswagen GTI SE (2.0T) which is (a little over) due for an emissions test.
A few weeks ago I had some rear-end bumper damage repaired, and while in the shop they cleared the trouble codes - which apparently also resets all the emissions test 'readiness' checks in the ECU.
I have since driven the car a few 100 miles, and also tried to follow the following 'drive cycle' to get everything 'ready' (although it's a little difficult to do all this in traffic, so I'm not 100% sure that I've definitely completed it exactly as-written):

- Start engine & idle for 2-3 minutes
- Drive at 45-55mph for 7 minutes
- Accelerate to engine speed of 5000rpm, lift off until engine speed is
  around 1200rpm
- Accelerate to 60-65rpm & cruise for 5 minutes
- Drive at 50-70mpg for 30-40 minutes

But there's no change - the following are still marked as 'not ready':

- Fuel System
- Catalytic Converter
- Oxygen Sensor

I'm lucky that the current corona-virus situation gives me a bit of an extension to get the emissions test done, but I'm at my wits end trying to figure out what to do next.
Prior to taking the car in for the bumper repairs there weren't any codes which caused the 'check engine' light to come on, and I'm not seeing anything unexpected now either.

<sub>I'm using an [OBDeleven](https://obdeleven.com/) scan tool if it makes any difference</sub>

Comment: One thing you don't mention is how much fuel you have in your tank. On most (if not all) OBDII systems, the fuel tank must be between 1/4 and 3/4 full, not above, not below (I believe for the entire time of the test). For at least the EVAP test (assuming that's what you're talking about with the "Fuel System"), if it isn't right, you'll never get it to pass that parameter.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 On my 1st attempt I don't know what the fuel level was, but on my 2nd attempt yesterday it was a little over half-full - so within that range.

Comment: Also, whether suggested or not, it can take several warm-up/cool-down cycles to pass the drive cycle. Don't give up just yet.